# I'm unable to center a div vertically through flex box even give height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to center a div through flex box in a react. But it's not working vertically in tutorial they give same styling and its work but on my side not working

This is app.js

```
<div className="App">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>
```

This is App.css

```
.App{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
 background: rgb(232, 232, 232);
}
```

Some people say that give height to body I also try it give `height:100%;` in `index.html file` using inline CSS but result is same so what's a problem how to center it in both directions vertically as well as horizontally in react through flex box??

Comment: can you add images how does it look and how do you want? so we can understand more

Comment: `justify-items: center;` should be `align-items: center;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
justify-items: center;
```

(which is an invalid statement)

to

```
align-items: center;
```